# Relatively positioned element with overflow: hidden and overlapping absolute positioned elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a Bootstrap menu with `dropdown-toggle` elements inside a slimScroll. The menu needs to be vertical (I achieve that through custom CSS; bare-bones concept fiddle is at: http://jsfiddle.net/HkAAn/) and have submenus which are wider than the container. Since I am using slimScroll, the entire left part needs to be wrapped in an element with `position: relative` and `overflow: hidden`. Of course, this crops the submenus. Is there any way for the submenus to not be cropped, while retaining the wrapper with `position: relative` and `overflow: hidden`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to alleviate the cropping, you must get the UL element that is your menu outside of the element that has "overflow: hidden".

Comment: But the whole point of scrolling is to scroll the top level menu items (which could surpass the height of the left element). How would I go about positioning the submenus then (and taking into account the scrolling)?

Comment: So your scrolling breaks if the menu isn't inside the element with "overflow: hidden"? Perhaps you could update the JSFiddle and demonstrate the scrolling part.

Comment: Positioning the sub-menus would get a little trickier and would probably require some javascript. I would guess a good place to start would be to get the mouse or element coordinates relative to the top left of the page and position the menu absolutely and set the top and left accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure how would I include slimScroll in JSFiddle, but like I said, the problem with having submenus (`ul ul`) separate from the top-level `ul` would be positioning with taking into account the scroll distance.

Comment: Under "External resources" on the left hand side you can add external JS files, if that was your concern...

Comment: Well, I can't link the slimScroll from GitHub, and I don't have it hosted.

Comment: Would setting the `z-index` allow the submenus to not be cropped?

Comment: No, there is no way to get an element to ignore the overflow: hidden while it is a child of the element styled with overflow: hidden.